# Using the dig command in python

Tags: python, dns, cname, dig

Just a forewarning, my python skills are almost nonexistent, but I’m trying to learn as I go.

I'm doing a few changes via our DNS control panel over the weekend to about 58 CNAMES (just changing the destination)

And rather than checking the changes have gone live for each individual record I was wondering if there was a way to script a list of digs for each CNAME in python?

The dig command I use would be something like this

```
dig @ns1.netnames.net www.rac.co.uk CNAME
```

and I would expect to see `rac-secure.gslb2.rac.co.uk` returned.

I tried something like:

```
import os
os.system( 'dig<exampledomain.com>'CNAME )
```

But that didn't appear to work (as I mentioned my python skills are lacking), am I on the right path, or should I be using something like dnspython? I have used the dnspython module before with (a lot) of help from the stack overflow community but I find the documentation really confusing.

Any pointers in the right direction would be greatly appreciated.

Regards

Chris.

Answer (score 56, accepted):

It's quite possible to invoke **dig** from python, it would probably save you work to just use a python library.  Take a look at [dnspython](http://www.dnspython.org/) which will probably do everything easier - plus you don't have to parse the output format.

```
import socket
import dns.resolver

# Basic query
for rdata in dns.resolver.query('www.yahoo.com', 'CNAME') :
    print rdata.target

# Set the DNS Server
resolver = dns.resolver.Resolver()
resolver.nameservers=[socket.gethostbyname('ns1.cisco.com')]
for rdata in resolver.query('www.yahoo.com', 'CNAME') :
    print rdata.target
```

Comment: Just to clarify, does the #basic query just check what your isp reports and the #set dns server check what the name server is reporting?

Comment: The basic query uses your default /etc/resolv.conf name servers, while the Set version allows you to specify which nameserver to call.

Comment: It should be dnspython instead of dynpython. but the 6 char limits in SO stops me from editing the answer above.

Comment: You need to install https://pypi.org/project/dnspython3/ to be working with python 3

Answer (score 8):

`os.system` is deprecated. Use [subprocess.Popen](http://docs.python.org/library/subprocess.html#module-subprocess):

```
import subprocess
import shlex

cmd='dig @ns1.netnames.net www.rac.co.uk +short'
# cmd='dig @ns1.netnames.net www.rac.co.uk CNAME'
proc=subprocess.Popen(shlex.split(cmd),stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
out,err=proc.communicate()
print(out)
# rac-secure.gslb.norwichunion.com.
```

Comment: I get a fairly large error when trying to run that:

  **Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "C:/Users/Chris/Documents/work/python/cname.py", line 5, in   <module>
      proc=subprocess.Popen(shlex.split(cmd),stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
    File "C:\Python26\lib\subprocess.py", line 623, in __init__
      errread, errwrite)
    File "C:\Python26\lib\subprocess.py", line 833, in   _execute_child
    startupinfo)
WindowsError: [Error 2] The system cannot find the file specified**

Comment: The error: `[Error 2] The system cannot find the file specified` implies (or at leasts suggests) that you don't have an executable named `dig`.

Comment: Ah, I just tried this at work and it works perfectly, must be something to do with my home desktop. Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

Found 2 additional Python libraries for dig-like commands. 
Both of them are called **pydig**.

1 ) [leonsmith/pydig](https://github.com/leonsmith/pydig)

Installation: 
  `pip install pydig`

Usage:

```
>>> import pydig
>>> pydig.query('example.com', 'A')
['93.184.216.34']
>>> pydig.query('www.github.com', 'CNAME')
['github.com.']
>>> pydig.query('example.com', 'NS')
['a.iana-servers.net.', 'b.iana-servers.net.']
```

2 ) [shuque/pydig](https://github.com/shuque/pydig).

Installation: 
 (as root) `python3 setup.py install`

Usage:

```
   pydig www.example.com
   pydig www.example.com A
   pydig www.example.com A IN
   pydig @10.0.1.2 example.com MX
   pydig @dns1.example.com _blah._tcp.foo.example.com SRV
   pydig @192.168.42.6 +dnssec +norecurse blah.example.com NAPTR
   pydig @dns2.example.com -6 +hex www.example.com
   pydig @192.168.72.3 +walk secure.example.com
```